# How to add visual effects on QGraphicsPixmapItem?

Tags: qt, qt5, qgraphicspixmapitem

I am using Qt 5.5.0.

I want to know a good way of adding (and removing) a simple effect on `QGraphicsPixmapItem`-s.

More specifically I have multiple `QGraphicsPixmapItem`-s moving on the scene. When they collide I want one item to turn white for a moment and then back to the original pixmap item.

Only thing I found in the docs for `QGraphicsPixmapItem` Class that could be what I need is the `virtual void   paint(QPainter * painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem * option, QWidget * widget)` member. But how do I use it to achieve my goal?

Comment: Don't use the `paint()` method for that kind of stuff. Check out [QGraphicsItemAnimation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitemanimation.html#details). Ich have not yet worked with it myself but it should give you anything you need.

Comment: From what I can see the `QGraphicsItemAnimation` is used for animating translation, rotation, scaling and similar effects. What I am looking for is to change the color of the actual opaque pixels in my `QGraphicsPixmapItem`.

Comment: A quick google search gave me one or two examples on people using it for other properties by deriving their own object from it. Another possibility would be using [the Animation Framework](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/animation-overview.html) as used in the [Animated Tiles example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-animation-animatedtiles-example.html).

Comment: Subclass `QGraphicsItem`. Add your own methods to pass the `QPixmap`. Use a flag of some sort that you enable when there is a collision and use a timer or something to reset that flag. Then in your overridden `QGraphicsItem::paint` method you can paint the pixmap if the collision flag is off, or fill the item with a white rectangle if the collision flag is on.

Comment: So, all you are asking is how to change the pixmap when something happens? You already know how to do that, since *you* set the pixmap to something in the first place. So what is the question, then?

Comment: @KubaOber That was the first idea I had, but then I would have an additional image for every object I want to apply this effect on. Also I thought switching pixmaps might be expensive. Am I wrong? Because I would be doing a lot of it. Almost as often as moving. Thanks

Comment: If anything changes, visually, there's a `QImage` backing store that has to be partially recomputed *anyway*, so you changing these pixmaps is, comparatively, small pickles and actually the fastest way of doing it. The image/pixmap can be computed instead of stored directly. You can have a method that computes the altered pixmap and stores it in a `QPixmapCache` for quick reuse.

Comment: @KubaOber Thank you! That was everything I wanted to know. I wish I could accept your comments as an answer.